# jsplumb detach makes endpoint hang

Tags: jsplumb

i do not want source endpoint to connect with target endpoint for same element so in connection event i am detaching current connection, like

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(info){
        if(info.sourceId === info.targetId){
            jsPlumb.detach(info.connection);
            return true;    
        }
});
```

but this makes my source end point get detached from div and endpoint hanging in same place after i drag my div as show in below image (dot is my source end point and rectangle in my target endpoint).

**Before creating connection**

[image]

**After creating connection**

[image]

in this i do not want source endpoint of Join_1 to make connection with target endpoint of Join_1.

I am using jsPlumb 1.7.2 version. is It a bug in this  how can i fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using beforeDrop event instead of connection, and inside the if condition return false.

```
jsPlumb.bind("beforeDrop", function(info){              
    if(info.sourceId === info.targetId){
        return false;    
    }
});
```

Also upgrade to version 1.7.4.

Hope it helps.